# Как объединить строки средствами SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть select который собирает таблицу такого вида и есть строки у которых одинаковые все поля, кроме последнего, включая id.

id | field1 | field2 | ... | A

id | field1 | field2 | ... | B

id | field1 | field2 | ... | C

Возможно ли средствами SQL объединить строки и склеить значения последнего столбца, чтобы получилось

id | field1 | field2 | ... | A; B; C

Comment: GROUP BY + string_agg()

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+string_agg)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий запрос:

```
WITH test_table AS(
  SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES
    (1, 123, 234, 7),
    (2, 123, 234, 8),
    (3, 123, 234, 9),
    (4, 234, 567, 17),
    (5, 234, 567, 16),
    (6, 234, 567, 15)
  ) AS T (id, field1, field2, value)
)

SELECT 
  MIN(id) as min_id,
  MAX(id) as max_id,
  field1,
  field2,
  STRING_AGG(value, '; ')profit
FROM test_table
GROUP BY field1, field2 --тут можно и id добавить, 
  --но думаю общий смысл понятен
```

Должно сработать, правда это не на всех версиях постгреса работает. Есть альтенативные решения для более ранних версий. Напишите, если не получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** не обращайте внимания на сортировку, тут она по умолчанию, как оптимизатор строки обрабатывает. Но можно задать при желании пользовольскую в предложении `STRING_AGG`

Почитайте:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/